# Undefined in react-native after importing

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app and I was almost finished, when I found this module: [react-native-ui-kitten](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten)

When I use the components, it works properly, but I saw that the have an example app: [kittenTricks](https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks)

In this app, there is an interessant way to handle the routes.

But when I implement it, I get weird error.

I import the Screens, this way: `import * as Screens from '../../screens/index';`

and when I print it in the console I get this:

[image]

So, it seems to me, as it's importing the whole Screens. When I click in `GridV2` I can see the object.

**But**

When I use: `Screens.GridV2` then I get *undefined* and the same happens with every screen, so I don't have a clue.

`GridV2` is so exported: `export class GridV2 extends`

And then, there's an `index` file which exports again: `export * from './grid2'` and then the `index` of screens.

Apparently, it is working, otherwise I couldn't see the objects when I print `Screens` but then, why `Screens.whatever` is giving an `undefined`?

I checked the dependencies, that they use in the example app, and they are the same as the dependencies I have. `react` and `react-native` are different versions, but I hope there's a way to get the objects of Screens in `react-native: 0.49.3`

I mean, I don't have a clue why it's happening, I was just wondering if there is a problem with the version of react-native.

Maybe someone had a similar problem and can tell me how to fix it. It's really making me crazy .

Comment: this is not a proper way of importing component classes

Comment: If I use "export default" and then I import it, it would work. But the question still, why I can see what Screens has inside and I can't use it thought. I was reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import and it seems ok, but maybe that way I can just import functions. Don't know

Comment: why dont you avoid * and import required components specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the answer I was looking for, and I asume it's not possible to do it that way. 
That's why the answer "I found" is just importing one by one the modules:

```
import gridV2 from '../../screens/navigation/grid2';
import sideMenu from '../../screens/navigation/sideMenu';
```

and then

```
        {
            id: 'GridV2',
            title: 'Grid Menu V2',
            screen: gridV2,
            children: []
        },
```

other side, I find this way better for reading.